# How to find accuracy of k-nn classifier

Tags: classification, image-recognition

I am doing coin recognition project  using matlab. I extracted features from test images and training images. I have 8761 training images and 2200 test images. Each image feature dimension is 192*1.so my trainData contains 192*8761features as well as testData contains 192*2200.I classified this datum with K-nn classifier. How can we calculate accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is the proportion of train samples, that were correctly classified.

If you are using `knnclassify` then look at the function [help text](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html). In short, the code will be:

```
knnclassify(trainData, testData, trainDataLabel)
```

Just make sure that rows are describing samples and columns are describing attributes. In your case trainData should have 8761 rows and 192 columns. Similarly testData should have 2200 rows and 192 columns. And trainDataLabel should describe the class of each sample in the trainData, hence it should have 8761 rows and 1 column.